# ASP.NET MVC RoleProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день! В базе данных имеется таблица с ролями и три таблицы, отвечающие за пользователей: заказчик, типография и администратор. Эти три таблицы связаны с таблицей ролей по roleId, т.е. у каждого пользователя есть определенная роль.

Далее, я пытаюсь настроить авторизацию, создаю свой MyRoleProvider, наследуюсь от RoleProvider и реализую методы GetAllRoles() и GetRoleForUser(string username). Но дело в том, что я не могу получить роль для конкретного пользователя по его имени, потому что у меня три таблицы с пользователями, а проверять каждую из них как-то не очень. Подскажите, как лучше это всё организовать.

Comment: Как то не очень иметь три таблицы с пользователями. Но раз уж они есть, то проверяйте их все\

Answer (score -2):

А зачем Вам три таблицы для пользователей? У этих пользователей настолько разный набор полей? Если да, тогда выделите общие поля в таблицу Users и создайте дополнительные таблицы, типа Admins и Customers